# React+Enzyme+Redux Error: Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I am new to Jest and Enzyme and I am trying to figure out how to solve this Error. I have tried all the possible solutions(also the ones that are on stackoverflow).

If this isn't the correct approach, I would appreciate being told what is.

### What I Want to Test?

A Component(named Company), which has a button 'Add' and on its click a modal(controlled by state) is opened.
So, I want to test whether on the button click, state used to control the visibility of the modal changes from 'false' to 'true'.

### My Approach So Far:

Going through the docs and a lot of answers on stackoverflow I have modified my code according to what worked for me

**Company.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal Col, Label, Row, Card, CardBody, CardColumns, CardHeader } from 'reactstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

const columns = [/*table data headers */ ]

export class Company extends React.Component {

    state = {
        show: false,
     
        }
        
    }
  
    handleShow = () => {...}

   
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchCompanies();
    }

    
    fetchCompanies = () => { /*API calls */ }       

    render() {
const options = {
            filterType: 'checkbox',
            selectableRows:false,
            customToolbar:() => {
                return <Button className="btn btn-primary"  id="companyAdd" onClick={this.handleShow}>Add</Button>
            }
        }
        return (
            <div>
            <Col xs="12" lg="12">
                <MUIDataTable
                columns={columns}
                options={options}
            />
            </Col>
            <Col xs="12" lg="12">
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.showChangePwd}></Modal>                
        </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({..});

function mapStateToProps(state) {..}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Company);
```

I am trying to find the button in option object(inside render)

**Company.test.js**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Company} from "../Company";
import { cleanup} from "@testing-library/react";

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { configure, mount, shallow , render} from "enzyme";

afterEach(cleanup)
it("renders without crashing", () => {
   expect(render(<Example/>))

})

it("renders button correctly", () => {
    const onButtonClickMock = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<Example updateSelectedDashboard={onButtonClickMock}/>)
    expect(wrapper.state('show')).toEqual(false);
    const button = wrapper.find('companyAdd');
    button.simulate('click') 
    expect(wrapper.state('show')).toEqual(true);
})
```

I have also tried `.dive()` even that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your css selectors :)

```
const button = wrapper.find('#companyAdd');
```

Comment: Where does this line go?

Comment: It's a definition of a button, on which he simulates the click. Just a misspelling correction. I thought it's obvious.

Comment: its still giving me the same error :( and i have even tried `<button data-test ='companyAdd'>Add </button> and tried to find in test code with ` const wrapper = component.find(`[data-test='companyAdd']`);` even this is not working

Comment: Ok, so I noticed just now that you use `shallow`, in taht case `find()` will go only one level deep. You have to either `mount` your component or use `dive()` (again, maybe it won't be enough, use console.log or `debug()` to inspect such element).

Comment: I have tried using `mount`, and `debug()` did  help me find a button with class 'companyAdd' but the error still remains the same.